# Synchronization data from 2 servers

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, dblink

I have some data from 2 databases and each database is on a different server. I want to sync from server A to server B.

My case is: I want to update/change `status_dt` to true for server A and server B. How to change `status_dt` in one query command?

Query :

```
SELECT 
    item_id, um_id, item_name, status_dt 
FROM 
    mst_item 
WHERE 
    status_dt IS NULL
    AND item_id IN (SELECT item_id
                    FROM dblink('hostaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=mrp-coba2 user=postgres password=abc',
                                'select item_id from mst_item') AS t1( item_id character(30)))
```

Comment: What version did u use ?

Comment: Postgresql v.9.5 @Brain90